# Select Multiple Views in Nativescript?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

i'm using nativescript vue and i'm just a beginner practicing it...

what i want is the identical nativescript code of this line below which is used in normal web application :

```
document.querySelectorAll(".my-class-name");
```

or

```
document.getelementsbyclassname("my-class-name");
```

i do actually know multiple ways of selecting a single View using ID like this line:

```
view.getViewById(parentOfView, "id-of-view");
```

so i'm wondering if there's a way of returning multiple views in an array in nativescript?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of an API that does that, but you could create one, I think, by enumerating the children of a parent view and testing for types and/or attributes (such as inspecting the classnames of the enumerated children and filtering accordingly).  See [View.eachChildView](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_core_view_.view.html#eachchild) for the basic enumerator you would need for such a thing.